# Query to list the logins and the databases they have access

Tags: sql

I am in the need of query to list all the users with their respective databases they have access to. Can somebody please help me.
Thanks,

Comment: What database system you using its different for each type.

Comment: SQL Server 2005.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll have to run something in each database.

```
SELECT db_name(), perm.state_desc, usr.name
FROM sys.database_permissions perm
JOIN sys.database_principals usr on perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
WHERE perm.class_desc = 'DATABASE'
```

Have a look at this, it explains the catalog views required

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=466